# SQL Server linear and parallel query processing: n! vs. (2n-2)!/(n-1)!

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm reading MS Exam book Exam 70-461:

I've noticed a strange formula for calculating amount of linear and parallel combinations of joins.

```
select A.col5, cum(c.col6) as colsum
from TableA AS A
join B on A.col1 = B.col1
join C on B.col2 = C.col2
where a.col3 = const1 
and b.col4 = const2
group by a.col5
```

Now

- Linear is `n!` - it's clear;
- But parallel is `(2n-2)!/(n-1)!` <-?! how do they get it?